# Почему во время передачи сообщения в kafka через процедуру HelloWorldProducerAvro происходит ошибка?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

Цель: передать свой класс (`AlertAvro`) в качестве значения в `kafka`. Сериализация класса происходит с помощью библиотеки `Avro`. Задание из книги `kafka` в действии. Глава 3.3.

Проблема: во время передачи сообщения в `kafka` (через процедуру `HelloWorldProducerAvro`) формируется ошибка:

> Error serializing Avro message

на строке:

```
producer.send(producerRecord);
```

Процедура отправки сообщения в kafka:

```
    public class HelloWorldProducerAvro {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Properties kaProperties = new Properties();
            kaProperties.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092, localhost:9093, localhost:9094");
            kaProperties.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, LongSerializer.class.getName());
            kaProperties.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, KafkaAvroSerializer.class.getName());
            kaProperties.put(AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, "http://localhost:8081");
    
            try (Producer<Long, org.kafkainaction.AlertAvro> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(kaProperties)) {
                org.kafkainaction.AlertAvro alertAvro = new org.kafkainaction.AlertAvro(12345L, Instant.now().toEpochMilli(), org.kafkainaction.AlertStatus.Critical);
                ProducerRecord<Long, org.kafkainaction.AlertAvro> producerRecord = new ProducerRecord<Long, org.kafkainaction.AlertAvro>("kinactionHelloworld", alertAvro.getSensorId(), alertAvro);
                producer.send(producerRecord);
            }
        }
    }
```

Весь стектрейс ошибок:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error serializing Avro message
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.serializeImpl(AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.java:101)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer.serialize(KafkaAvroSerializer.java:53)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer.serialize(Serializer.java:62)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.doSend(KafkaProducer.java:1015)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:962)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:847)
    at ru.work.chat.avro.HelloWorldProducerAvro.main(HelloWorldProducerAvro.java:25)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:542)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:597)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633)
    at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:178)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:498)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:603)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:246)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:351)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:373)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1309)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1242)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1128)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:1057)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1430)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1401)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.sendHttpRequest(RestService.java:199)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.httpRequest(RestService.java:256)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.registerSchema(RestService.java:356)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.registerSchema(RestService.java:348)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.registerSchema(RestService.java:334)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.registerAndGetId(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:168)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.register(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:222)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.register(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:198)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.serializeImpl(AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.java:70)
    ... 6 more
    

    **файл pom.xml**
    <properties>
            <java.version>17</java.version>
            <avro.version>1.11.0</avro.version>
            <confluent.version>5.3.0</confluent.version>
        </properties>
    
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                <optional>true</optional>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
                <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
                <!--            <version>2.7.0</version>-->
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
                <artifactId>avro</artifactId>
                <version>${avro.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
                <artifactId>kafka-schema-registry-client</artifactId>
                <version>${confluent.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
                <artifactId>kafka-avro-serializer</artifactId>
                <version>${confluent.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>confluent</id>
                <url>https://packages.confluent.io/maven/</url>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>
                                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            </exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
                    <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${avro.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>schema</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/myavro/</sourceDirectory>
                                <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java/</outputDirectory>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    

    **Файл схемы avsc:**
    {
        "namespace" : "org.kafkainaction",
        "type": "record",
        "name": "AlertAvro",
        "fields": [
            {"name":"sensor_id", "type":"long", "doc":"The unique id that identifies the sensor"},
            {"name":"time", "type":"long", "doc":"Time alert generated as UTC milliseconds from epoch"},
            {"name": "status",
                "type": {"type":"enum", "name":"AlertStatus", "symbols":["Critical","Major","Minor","Warning"]},
                "doc":"Allowed values sensors use for current status"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.